# android studion 3.4.2 gradle project sync fail error, Error fail to resolve Dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle

i have just installed android studio 3.4.2 and created an empty activity project, but when i try to make the apk file or build the project i got fellow errors, please help, i have tried many methods but i dont understand whats the problem, i didnt add any code, just want to build a default project.but android studio fail to sync

```
    ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.core:core:1.1.0-rc01
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-rc01
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0-rc01
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: appcompat
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
---------------------------------------
build.gradle Module value is the default content of android studio 3.4.2
build.gradle project value is the default content of android studio 3.4.2
```

i dont understand why android studio cant build its default setting project.???

Comment: please post your build.gradle files

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you need to check the follow steps:

1- make sure your gradle.build(Project) contains :

```
  allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://maven.google.com'
        }

    }
}
```

2- and build.gradle(module) contains this line in dependencies:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\EmdadSystem.gradle\caches 
remove folder caches and try again sync gradle